# What's the difference between before, until, and unless?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Here are two fill-in-the-blank questions in my grammar exercises.

1. A man is not old ______ regrets take the place of dreams.
2. Success always hides behind the next corner in the road, so you'll never know how close it lies ______ you turn the corner.

When going through the questions, my classmates argued that *before*, *until*, and *unless* all sounds fine in the sentence. However, only one of them was considered correct, which I couldn't remember clearly.

Would anyone be so kind as to point me the correct answers out and show me why? Thanks in advance!

(*I'm not a native speaker, so sorry for any mistake. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three words would be *grammatically* correct, but not all grammatical sentences make sense.

Sentence (1) refers to the passage of time in a person's life, so *unless* is not appropriate. *Until* sounds much more idiomatic than *before.*

I think all three might be possible in Sentence (2). *Unless you turn the corner* implies that you might choose not to go round it at all. Assuming that you *are* going to continue along the road, *until* sounds better than *before.*